# Send parcelable object from second_activiy to main_activity, is it possible?

Tags: android

I´m trying to send a parcelabe object from second activity to main activity, but the main activity is still in the Activities´ Stack, so I have two main activity running, I know this because I have a button to close the app and I have to press the button twice, one per each main activity.

Is it possible to send a parcelable object to main activity without open again the main activity? Is it impossible or I must use sql Lite instead of?

Is other command to use instead of `startActivity()` to call an activity that is now in the activities stack?

My goal saves in a list the new document that the user has saved in the second activity and shown it in the main activity all the documents save.

I can recover the data send for the second activity to the main activity, but I have two main activity running...

Any advice?

Thanks in advance.

My code:

```
public class Albaran implements Parcelable {
private String numalbaran;
private boolean tienefoto;
private boolean incidencia;
private Uri imageToUploadUri;

public Albaran(){

}

public Albaran(String numalbaran, boolean tienefoto, boolean incidencia, Uri imageToUploadUri) {
    this.numalbaran = numalbaran;
    this.tienefoto = tienefoto;
    this.incidencia = incidencia;
    this.imageToUploadUri = imageToUploadUri;
}

protected Albaran(Parcel in) {
    numalbaran = in.readString();
    tienefoto = in.readByte() != 0;
    incidencia = in.readByte() != 0;
    imageToUploadUri = in.readParcelable(Uri.class.getClassLoader());
}

public static final Creator<Albaran> CREATOR = new Creator<Albaran>() {
    @Override
    public Albaran createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Albaran(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Albaran[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Albaran[size];
    }
};

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(numalbaran);
    dest.writeByte((byte) (tienefoto ? 1 : 0));
    dest.writeByte((byte) (incidencia ? 1 : 0));
    dest.writeParcelable(imageToUploadUri, flags);
}
```

}

I call to the second activity in my main activity

```
public void recogerDatos(View view){  //Onclick
    intent = new Intent(this,RecogerActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

I call to the first activity from my second activity

```
public void guardarAlbaran(View view){ //Save data when button is pressed
    Albaran NuevoAlbaran = new Albaran(numAlbaran.toString(),incidenciaCheckbox.isChecked(), incidenciaCheckbox.isChecked(), imageToUploadUri);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("Albaran", NuevoAlbaran);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();                                  //Finalizar Actividad
}
```

I read the data from the parcelable objects in my main activity

```
Albaran nuevoAlbaran;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    nuevoAlbaran = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("Albaran");

}
```

Comment: see `Activity#startActivityForResult()` method

Comment: Thank you pskink, I ´ve achieved it using startActivityResult.